# Adding specific information to a local file

Tags: database-design, datafile

I have several files on a webserver (not stored in the database). I'd like to store several information to this specific file. The user should be able to post comments about this file.

My question is:

What is the best way in order to store information in a database in addition to a file that is stored on a webserver... How do I connect both parts?

Comment: My first thought was to create a table with two columns, one fo the filepath, another to store comments. If you need multiple comments for each file, then you need to have a slightly different table(s) design.

Comment: @SQLRockstar: Why not write a full answer?

Comment: @Daniel: What are you tring to accomplish? This type of design probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: Do you mean "store information *about* this specific file"?  Or are you talking about writing data to the file itself?

Comment: @Jon: This is exactly what I think as well. Might not be a good idea, but I have no idea how to do this in a different way. What I'm trying to do is to build up a WebDav server, where files will be stored by the user. Those files are supposed to be listed/presented on a website. The user should be able to search for those files, comment them, etc.
Unfortunately... in the moment when those files will be "uploaded"/created on the server, they are getting random names like "ASD564A8A6S54EASEAS864.doc", so in this exact moment I don't even know the name of this file.

Comment: @mdoyle: I mean adding information to the database that is not part of this file. Additional information objects but not file information in a sense of size, file format, etc.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? There may be in-built solutions designed to solve this problem.

Comment: I haven't decided yet. I'd like to have at least a rough idea for the right way to do it. So, all options are open...

Answer (score 1):

For a SQL Server solution, [`FILESTREAM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) (or [`FILETABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx) if you can use SQL Server 2012) was built to solve this type of problem.

This solution will allow you to store the files in a central network location (most importantly, not on a web server box) outside the database, and manipulate metadata information within the database.

As mentioned in my comment, other RDBMS systems may also have similar capabilities (I'm not familiar enough with them to say, though).